# Assistance needed in speeding up Macro code

Tags: excel, vba

Need help in optimizing the below block of code to copy and paste a range of selection from one sheet to another sheet. 
I have 3-4 blocks similar to the one below. Would be helpful if somone could help out with an optimized version of the code below

Note: I am a coding Beginner

```
Sheets("Company Profile").Select
    Range("D15").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(client_name).Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Range("D2").Select
```

Getting expected result but need to speed up

Comment: Turn off screen updating, events and calculations.

Comment: [Avoid using `Select` and `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1|217.4492). Not only is it slow, it's also error-prone.

Comment: Also, read up on why its not recommended to use things like `Select` and `Activate` in `VBA`. **Tip**: the way you are performing the copy, basically you pasting things into clipboard and then pasting from clipboard. If you do something like: `<your range>.Copy <destination>`, it's a copy without using clipboard (as such). This way you are not clogging your memory with unwanted stuff